# ImportError: No module named astropy, after installing astropy in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, astropy

So I am trying to work with `Astropy` and I definitely downloaded it. However, I am getting an error.  I am trying to work in Python 2 rather than Python 3.

The code was just:

```
import astropy
astropy.test()
```

This is the error given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/....../Random.py", line 1, in <module>
  import astropy
  ImportError: No module named astropy
```

Comment: such a basic error just means you havent installed the module

Comment: Well, no I did.  The module IS downloaded but for whatever reason, it doesn't accept me using Python 2, which I need to use for other modules.  Please I realize that the first response is to say it is a basic error but I wouldn't be asking if it was basic.

Comment: Are you sure, it has been `pip install`ed? Or however you installed it. Perhaps there is a version incompatibility if you are sure you have installed it

Comment: It doesn't work either way for whatever reason.  When I switch from Python 2 or 3, throws up some kind of error.  Any ideas on how to point which version I want it to install to?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `anaconda` or `astropy`, and it depends how you are installing it. Is this within a virtual environment?

Comment: Did you do `conda install astropy`?  Have you activated your conda environment?

Comment: Can you install and import other packages in your conda environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the fix was removing Python 3.4, deleting directory, reinstalled 2.7 and Pypm Astropy.  Not sure exactly what happened but that was the fix...

Comment: Were you mixing up anaconda and activepython on your path (i.e. why bring up pypm)?

Comment: Originally, I tried to install astropy using pypm but there seemed to be a path issue.  Then I tried Anaconda to see if it could use that which I realized my IDE wasn't setup to use so I went back and tried to troubleshoot what pypm was doing wrong.  I think it was the order in which I installed everything which sounds really silly but seemed to be the issue.

Comment: pypm is the installer that comes with ActivePython which you must have installed at some point.  Anaconda is a separate, unrelated Python distribution.  Both can coexist on your system, but when you run a command like `pip` or `python` you need to check which distribution's copy of that command you're running by using `with`.  It's going to depend on what's earlier on your `$PATH` environment variable.  Similarly if you want to use an IDE with any of these python distributions you need to specify in your IDE which one you want to use (most IDEs will support multiple Pythons as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try a few things at the shell to examine your environment and possibly understand your problem:

```
which python
which conda
conda list
```